# Regular expression to Redirect from IIS

Tags: regex, iis, redirect

I am new in regular expression. Now i am writing a rewrite rule to redirect page. I have a url which is

```
http://abc dot com/blog/social-media-page/
```

now i have to redirect above url to this url through IIS.

```
http://blog dot abc dot com/social-media-page
```

how can i handle this by regular expression.

Comment: Is it `'abc dot com'` or `abc.com`

Comment: Is it only this page, or all pages from the previous domain to the new vanity URL? The reason I ask is that this may be achieved through IIS as a 301 redirect instead.

Comment: all the url which contain /blog should redirect to blog.abc.com through IIS redirect

Comment: Can you tell how can i achieve this using IIS redirect? Becuase it needs regex

Answer (score 0):

search this :

```
http:\/\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)
```

and replace with this :

```
http://\2 dot \1
```

regex demo here : http://regex101.com/r/jZ4vC2

Comment: how can i write ur regex in IIS

Comment: itsactually .com not dot com

Answer (score 0):

You can use back references:

`'http:\/\/([a-z]+)\s([a-z]+)\s([a-z]+)\/([^\/]*)'`

and replace the match with

`'http://\4 dot \1 dot \3'`

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/rE8lP6

Answer (score 0):

my problem is this, Google has indexed my pages with the structure
 `http://www.donbalon.com/noticia/detalle/4623/ES/descubren-en-argentina-los-secretos-mejor-guardados-de-leo-messi` and I want to do a 301 redirect to the same URL but without the "ES" parameter, that is, `http://www.donbalon.com/noticia/detalle/4623/descubren-en-argentina-los-secretos-mejor-guardados-de-leo-messi` . In the web.config file I have the following but can not get redirected correctly.
Anyone know how to do it from a rule web.config file?

```html
<rule name = "RedirectWithoutIsoCode" stopProcessing = "true">
                   <match url = ". *" />
                   <conditions>
                       <add input = "{HTTP_HOST}" pattern = "^http:\/\/www\.donbalon\.com\/noticias\/detalle\/(\d+)\/([A-Z]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)"/>
                   </conditions>
                   <action type="Redirect" url="www.donbalon.com/detalle/noticia/{R:1}/{R:3}" redirectType="Permanent" />
               </rule>
```

Thanks

EDIT

Finally I used protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute (Object sender, EventArgs e) in global.asax. With a regular expression I detect the portion of text I want to delete and built the new URL without that portion. Then I use a 301 redirect response object for the current request

```
        protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Regex expresionDetalle = new Regex(@"/([a-z]+)/detalle/(\d+)/([A-Z]{2})/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]*)");

        Regex expresionCodigoIso = new Regex(@"ES|AR|GT|EC|US|VE|UY");
        string[] partesURL;
        StringBuilder nuevaURL;

        string currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;

        if (expresionDetalle.IsMatch(currentUrl))
        {
            partesURL = currentUrl.Split('/');
            nuevaURL = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string s in partesURL)
            {
                if (!expresionCodigoIso.IsMatch(s) &&
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                {
                    nuevaURL.Append('/');
                    nuevaURL.Append(s);
                }
            }

            Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
            Response.RedirectPermanent(nuevaURL.ToString());
        }
    }
```